# Calculating EY with an even function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let X ∼f(x−θ), where f(x−θ) is symmetric about θ.  I want to find EY of the following function Y.

Y= 1 for |x−θ|<2 and 0 otherwise.

Please tell me if this interpretation of my question is correct.  We are integrating over a circle with radius 2 so our double integral would be the following:

$$ EY= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} 1 f(x−θ) dxdθ$$

I'm not so sure how to deal with f(x−θ) given that its an even function. I mean this can be anything, and its not really a specific function.  Can anyone help me with this?  Thanks.

Comment: Are $x$ and $\theta$ 2D vectors?

Comment: no, I don't think so... I just thought of them as points.

Comment: You mean points in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Well, I thought they were when I read the question.  If it were vectors, would it make more sense and if so, how?

Comment: If they were vectors then at least I would understand the double integral you displayed.

Comment: Yes, I just checked with a colleague and they're vectors.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's formulate the question a little better.

(1) We have a random vector variable $\vec X=(X_x,X_y)$.

(2) The joint density of the random variables $X_x,X_y$ is $f(x-\theta_x,y-\theta_y)$.

(3) where  $\vec{\theta}=(\theta_x,\theta_y)$ is a given vector.

(4) We know that $f(x-\theta_x,y-\theta_y)$ is simmetrical around $\vec \theta$.

(5) The definition of the random variable $Y$

$$Y=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{ if } |(X_x-\theta_x,X_y-\theta_y)|<2\\
0,&\text{ otherwise. }
\end{cases},$$

(6) that is $Y$ indicates if $\vec X$ fell in the circle of radious $2$ centered at $\vec \theta$. Let the disk defined by this circle be called $\mathscr C.$

(7) The task is to calculate the following probability

$$E[Y]=P(\vec X\in \mathscr C).$$

---

The solution, in theory, is

$$E[Y]=\iint_{\mathscr C}f(x-\theta_x,y-\theta_y) \ dxdy.$$

Introducing polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\varphi),\ y=r\sin(x)$ we have

$$E[Y]=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\int_0^2rf(r\cos(\varphi)-\theta_x,r\sin(\varphi)-\theta_y)\ dr\right]d\varphi$$

where $r$ in front of $f$ is the Jacobian.

Comment: So the area would be $4\pi$ right?

Comment: The result depends on $f$ as well.